# Terminal not started in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-terminal, process

Ubuntu 18.04 failed to start terminal. It shows an Error message - -failed to execute child process gnome-terminal. Please help me to start terminal in my system.

Answer (score 1):

First install Terminator or Xterm to get a working terminal. Open Synaptic Package Manager and install it there.

Check the permissions on the files in your home folder

```
find $HOME ! -user $USER
```

In particular be on the lookout for files in `.dbus`

You may resolve all permissions at once with

```
sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER $HOME
```

This resolved my identical issues today. I found these solutions in this thread: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=279168

Additionally, I removed the files in `$HOME/.dbus/session-bus`, removed Chrome Remote Desktop and its data in `$HOME/.config/chrome-remote-desktop` and rebooted. My assumption is that Chrome Remote Desktop restarted itself during an update and wrote some files as root in the home folder.

Comment: uninstalling chrome-remote-desktop did it for me